# Batch file to convert .xlsx to .xml

Tags: batch-file, ssis

I have a bunch of .xls/.xlsx files being dumped from SSIS tool. Figuring out how to write a batch script to convert .xls/.xlsx files to .xml directly. Changing the extension and renaming it doesn;t fix it. So it will have to open and saved as .xml

Any help here would be appreciated.

Thanks,
V

Comment: Can't be done with a batch file.  You will need to use Vbscript or some other language.

Comment: Take the [tour], read [ask], and [MCVE]. Search for [excel file converter to xml](https://www.google.com/search?source=hp&ei=9unpW9eJB96x0PEPpIeDsAw&q=excel+file+converter+to+xml&oq=Excel+file+converter+to+xml&gs_l=psy-ab.1.0.0i22i30l10.13144.25224..28729...0.0..0.79.1278.27......0....1..gws-wiz.......0j0i131j0i10.EZktn_xAneE) and you'll find tools that can do the job. Run `help for` and learn to iterate over files, invoking whatever conversion tool you adopt.

Comment: `xlsx` is in fact little more than zipped `XML` internally. My point is - `XML` is way too broad, but you do need just any XML, you need specificly structured one, and we have no idea what it should look like. Renaming files  obviously does not change their contents or format. At the very least please be more specific and verbose and provide examples of what you have, what you need, and what you have done. As @Squashman said you will need learn something like VBscript or VBA or some other more powerful language than batch file.